# Spring Test doesn't rollback REQUIRES_NEW, any workaround?

Tags: spring, junit, transactions, integration-testing

To my surprise running JUnit test with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` doesn't roll back `REQUIRES_NEW` transactions. The [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6908) doesn't get much attention.

Is there a work around to get Spring to properly handle `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction?